# Fill PDF form using html

Tags: html, mysql, pdf

I'm developing an app, and I need to fill in some fields in a PDF that already contain information.

I have to pass data from sql database trow html to the PDF.

How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/.
**Please** provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fill a PDF with html, you should look at this post already answered which use js and jquery [link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218666/fill-pdf-form-with-javascript)