# Get page number pdf object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am using this construction for view the .pdf file:

```
<object id="yeah" data="D:\Java.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="D:\Java.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

I haven't found any information: 
 
1. Can I get number of current viewed page in document by using JS? 
2. Can I open document on page which I want?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted two questions:

**#1: Can I get the page number of the current page that is viewed by using JS:**

No, it is very hard to establish a communication between the JavaScript in your browser and the JavaScript in your PDF viewer. See for instance [PDF hostContainer callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837002/pdf-hostcontainer-callback), but please understand that what I describe in that answer doesn't work anymore in most browsers, and that PDF viewers such as Preview, Chrome PDF Viewer, pdf.js,... don't support that functionality.

**#2: Can I open a PDF document on a specific page?**

Yes, you can do so by composing the link as described in the [PDF Open Parameters](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) document by Adobe. This is also explained in the answers to this question: [Open a pdf file programmatically at a named destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423922/open-a-pdf-file-programmatically-at-a-named-destination)

This example was copy/pasted from Adobe's document:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks&page=2
```

As you can see, you need to add `#` after the URL and pass a `page` parameter of which the value is the page number. You'll find many other examples in that document, but once more: be aware that this is the behavior of Adobe Reader. Other viewers may ignore those parameters.

Comment: The [PDF Open Parameters](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) link above is paywalled / restricted. This is a publicly available PDF from Adobe on the same topic: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf [dated April 2007]